# Fill dynamically Accordion component with web service response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dynamic, fetch, accordion

I'm fairly new in react native. I try to fill dynamically Accordion component with response from webservice. I arrive to correctly render section but not their content, let see the code.

```
renderHeader(section){
    return (
        <View style={{height: 60}}>
            <Body>
            <DefaultText>T {section} :        
              {(this.state.reservations).length} créneaux disponible</DefaultText>
            </Body>
        </View>
    )
}

renderContent(){
    return (
        <View 
           style={{justifyContent: 'center',
           alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}
        >
                {
                    this.state.reservations.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <DefaultText>
                                {item.start}
                            </DefaultText>
                        )
                })}
        </View>
    )
}

<Accordion
    sections={this.state.idPlayGround}
    renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
    renderContent={this.renderContent}
/>
```

This request correspond to values who I need to input in my sections :

```
fetch(WEB_SERV + "searchTerrains", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'surfaceID=' + this.state.surface + '&p_heureDebut=' + this.state.hour + '&p_date=' + (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? moment(this.state.date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY") : this.state.date) + '&p_double=' + this.state.matchType
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            let idPlayGround = [];
            for(let i=0; i<responseJson.length; i++){
                idPlayGround.push(responseJson[i].TER_DESIGNATION);
            }
            this.setState({
                idPlayGround: idPlayGround,
                show: false,
            });
        }).catch(console.log)
```

And this one correspond to values for my content :

```
fetch(WEB_SERV + "searchCreneaux", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        body: 'surfaceID=' + this.state.surface + '&p_heureDebut=' + this.state.hour + '&p_date=' + (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? moment(this.state.date, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("MM/DD/YYYY") : this.state.date) + '&p_double=' + this.state.matchType
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            let hTerrains = [];
            responseJson.map((item) => {
                hTerrains.push({
                    't_start': item.HEURE_DEBUT,
                    't_designation': item.TER_DESIGNATION,
                    't_id': item.TER_ID
                });
            });
            this.setState({
                reservations: hTerrains
            })
        }).catch(console.log)
```

I just need **t_start** and maybe **t_designation**, the other values doesn't usefull in this case.

I don't know where I need to split my values, in fetch in render or maybe a method with map. I'am rather lost and I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Any reason why you are setting state in responseJson.map? You already have this.setState({
                reservations: hTerrains
            }) at the end.

Comment: You right I don't need it

Comment: can you  update the question and let us know your issue again ?

Comment: Same problem as at start, I don't kown how to input t_start value in render content correctly. **reservations** contains **t_start* and **t_designation**. For each **t_desgnation** who are the same as the section (idPlayground), I need to render his **t_start** in the correspondant section.

Comment: Isnt it   <DefaultText>
                                {item.t_start}
                            </DefaultText> that you wanted to display? Would it be possible for you to create a fiddle for us to understand issue that you are seeing?

Comment: I just find a solution for my problem I edited in few minute. Thank's a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution it was simple. I had just needed to compare **t_designation** by **section** and render **t_start** when they equals, see the code below :

```
renderContent(section){
    return (
        <View style={{flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent:'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                {
                    this.state.reservations.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <DefaultText key={index}
                                style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', textAlign: 'center', }}>
                                {
                                    item.t_designation === section ?
                                        item.t_start
                                        :
                                        ""
                                }
                            </DefaultText>
                        )
                })}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Thank's for your help